# Как сделать так, чтобы при запущенном Activiti Modeler в моём приложении работали service task и script task, стоящие после таймеров?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

Если одновременно с моим приложением запущен *Activiti Modeler*, и если он использует ту же базу для движка `Activiti`, что и моё приложение, то `service task` и `script task`, стоящие после таймеров (`boundary timer event` и `intermediate timer catching event`), не работают, и вызывают ошибки. Описания ошибок такие: *"couldn't instantiate <полное_имя_класса>"* - для `service task` (если указан класс <полное_имя_класса>), *"Can't find scripting engine for 'groovy'"* - для `script task`. Если я использую `Spring`, и приписываю бин в `service task`, то появляется ошибка с таким описанием: *"Could not execute service task expression"*.

При этом находил и пробовал такую рекомендацию:

> Для того, чтобы всё работало без ошибок, необходимо скомпилировать классы, которые используются service task, и положить их со всеми пакетами, в которых они находятся, в папку WEB_INF/classes. Также, чтобы не возникало проблем с груви, необходимо в WEB_INF/lib закинуть jar-файл этой библиотеки, причём тот, который используется основной программой (той же версии).

Это работает, если не используются бины `Spring`. Но это тоже костыльное решение, и хотелось бы вообще отключить в *Activiti Modeler* отлов событий таймера в базе. Пока не нашёл, как это сделать.

Смотрел документацию для системного администратора. Там написано про свойства, которые можно прописать в *activiti-app.properties*. Нашёл несколько свойств, которые судя по описанию, могут мне помочь, и попытался установить для них нужные значения:

```
elastic-search.server.type=none
event.processing.enabled=false
event.generation.enabled=false
```

Но это тоже ничего не дало.

PS Использую Activiti 6.0.0.

Comment: Задал подобный вопрос на англоязычной версии ресурса, и мне там ответили, что это ограничение данного приложения, и оно исправлено в Activiti Cloud 7. Пока не считаю это полноценным решением, поэтому жду других ответов.